# After extracting .xls ole - file is empty with Microsoft Excel but readable with apache-poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a .doc file with an embedded .xls and an embedded .doc.
I can extract both files and save it.
When I want to open the .doc - document everything is fine.
When I want to open the .xls - document it is empty, the editor opens nothing, I also dont see any empty cells nothing.

So I tried to read again with apache-poi the extracted .xls document and when I look at the Sheet-Name or Content of the cells - everything is there.

Do you have any ideas what it is?

My setup is:
apache-poi version 3.15 (I also tried some minor versions)
The word and excel files were created with office 2007.

the code - part:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(file);

    POIOLE2TextExtractor poiole2TextExtractor = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(fs);
    POITextExtractor[] embeddedExtractors = ExtractorFactory.getEmbededDocsTextExtractors(poiole2TextExtractor);

    for (POITextExtractor textExtractor : embeddedExtractors) {
        // If the embedded object was an Excel spreadsheet.
        if (textExtractor instanceof ExcelExtractor) {
            ExcelExtractor excelExtractor = (ExcelExtractor) textExtractor;
            DirectoryNode directoryNode = (DirectoryNode) excelExtractor.getRoot();


            HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(directoryNode, true);

            File tmp = new File(targetfolder, "test.xls");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tmp);

            hssfWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            hssfWorkbook.close();
        }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I've just tried it with libre office and there I can open the file.. maybe it depends on Office 2007

Comment: 2016 - also doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

So somehow i found the problem:

For HSSFWorkbook I needed to set the following attribute:

```
hssfWorkbook.setHidden(false);
```

For all formats xlsx (2007) if you call that method, you will get an NotImplementedException - so you have to fix that manually... I found the solution as follows:

```
String workbookContent = new String(ZipFileUtils.getInnerFile(tmp, "xl/workbook.xml"), "UTF-8");
                workbookContent = workbookContent.replaceFirst("visibility=\"hidden\"", "");
                ZipFileUtils.replaceZippedFile(tmp, "xl/workbook.xml",
                        workbookContent.getBytes( "UTF-8"), new FileOutputStream(tmp2));
```

where tmp = My Extracted xlsx File and I save it to an new one at the momement tmp2

Comment: Can you raise a bug in the [Apache POI bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI) for the lack of a working XSSF `setHidden` method? Should be fairly quick to fix, especially as you've worked out what the method needs to do!